# Networking using run loop

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading

I have an application which uses some external library for analytics. Problem is that I suspect it does some things synchronously, which blocks my thread and makes watchdog kill my app after 10 secs (0x8badf00d code). It is really hard to reproduce (I cannot), but there are quite few cases "in the wild".

I've read some documentation, which suggested that instead creating another thread I should use run-loops. Unfortunately the more I read about them, the more confused I get. And the last thing i want to do is release a fix which will break even more things :/

What I am trying to achieve is:

From main thread add a task to the run-loop, which calls just one function: initMyAnalytics(). My thread continues running, even if initMyAnalytics() gets locked waiting for network data. After initMyAnalytics() finishes, it quietly quits and never gets called again (so it doesnt loop or anything).

Any ideas how to achieve it? Code examples are welcome ;)
Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a run loop in that case. Run loops' purpose is to proceed events from various sources sequentially in a particular thread and stay idle when they have nothing to do. Of course, you can detach a thread, create a run loop, add a source for your function and run the run loop until the function ends. The same as you can use a semi-trailer truck to carry your groceries home.

Here, what you need are dispatch queues. Dispatch queues are First-In-First-Out data structures that run tasks asynchronously. In contrary to run loops, a dispatch queue isn't tied to a particular thread: the working threads are automatically created and terminated as and when required.

As you only have one task to execute, you don't need to create a dispatch queue. Instead you will use an existing global concurrent queue. A concurrent queue execute one or more tasks concurrently, which is perfectly fine in our case. But if we had many tasks to execute and wanted each task to wait for its predecessor to end, we would need to create a serial queue.

So all you have to do is:

- create a task for your function by enclosing it into a [Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29)
- get a global queue using `dispatch_get_global_queue`
- add the task to the queue using `dispatch_async`.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    initMyAnalytics();
});
```

`DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` is a macro that evaluates to `0`. You can get different global queues with different priorities. The second parameter is reserved for future use and should always be `0`.